# Mod mono server doesn't host the webpages placed in /var/www/html and displays an error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, mono, mod-mono

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application developed in windows. I am trying to port it to linux using mod mono. I have Mono 2.10.5 installed and would like to use .Net framework 4.0. I have placed the webpages in a folder in /var/www/html. I get the following error messages while trying to access the url "localhost/mydata/"

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00047] in /home/chanchal/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-2.10.5/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:785 
at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in /home/chanchal/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-2.10.5/mcs/class/corlib/System/AppDomain.cs:762 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in /home/chanchal/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-2.10.5/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:535 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.AddAssemblyByName (System.String name) [0x00057] in /home/chanchal/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-2.10.5/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.UI/TemplateParser.cs:621
```

The version information is as follows:

```
 Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.5 (tarball Fri Oct 28 10:20:24 IST 2011); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1
```

My httpd.conf file is as follows:

```
### Section 1: Global Environment
ServerTokens OS

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

PidFile run/httpd.pid

Timeout 60

KeepAlive Off

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

    <IfModule worker.c>
    StartServers         4
    MaxClients         300
    MinSpareThreads     25
    MaxSpareThreads     75
    ThreadsPerChild     25
    MaxRequestsPerChild  0
    </IfModule>

    Listen 80

    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
    LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
    LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
    LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so

    Include conf.d/*.conf

    Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_mono.conf

    User apache
    Group apache

    ServerAdmin root@localhost

    UseCanonicalName Off

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/html">

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        AllowOverride None

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disabled


    </IfModule>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

    AccessFileName .htaccess

    <Files ~ "^\.ht">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </Files>

    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    DefaultType text/plain

    <IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    #   MIMEMagicFile /usr/share/magic.mime
        MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
    </IfModule>

    HostnameLookups Off

    ErrorLog logs/error_log

    LogLevel warn

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # "combinedio" includes actual counts of actual bytes received (%I) and sent (%O); this
    # requires the mod_logio module to be loaded.
    #LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio

    #CustomLog logs/access_log common

    #CustomLog logs/referer_log referer
    #CustomLog logs/agent_log agent

    CustomLog logs/access_log combined

    ServerSignature On

    Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

    <Directory "/var/www/icons">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
        # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
        DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
    </IfModule>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8

    AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

    AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
    AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
    AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
    AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

    AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
    AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
    AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
    AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
    AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
    AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
    AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
    AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
    AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
    AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
    AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
    AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
    AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
    AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
    AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
    AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

    AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
    AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
    AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
    AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

    #
    # DefaultIcon is which icon to show for files which do not have an icon
    # explicitly set.
    #
    DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif

    #
    # AddDescription allows you to place a short description after a file in
    # server-generated indexes.  These are only displayed for FancyIndexed
    # directories.
    # Format: AddDescription "description" filename
    #
    #AddDescription "GZIP compressed document" .gz
    #AddDescription "tar archive" .tar
    #AddDescription "GZIP compressed tar archive" .tgz

    #
    # ReadmeName is the name of the README file the server will look for by
    # default, and append to directory listings.
    #
    # HeaderName is the name of a file which should be prepended to
    # directory indexes.
    ReadmeName README.html
    HeaderName HEADER.html

    #
    # IndexIgnore is a set of filenames which directory indexing should ignore
    # and not include in the listing.  Shell-style wildcarding is permitted.
    #
    IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t

    #
    # DefaultLanguage and AddLanguage allows you to specify the language of
    # a document. You can then use content negotiation to give a browser a
    # file in a language the user can understand.
    #
    # Specify a default language. This means that all data
    # going out without a specific language tag (see below) will
    # be marked with this one. You probably do NOT want to set
    # this unless you are sure it is correct for all cases.
    #
    # * It is generally better to not mark a page as
    # * being a certain language than marking it with the wrong
    # * language!
    #
    # DefaultLanguage nl
    #
    # Note 1: The suffix does not have to be the same as the language
    # keyword --- those with documents in Polish (whose net-standard
    # language code is pl) may wish to use "AddLanguage pl .po" to
    # avoid the ambiguity with the common suffix for perl scripts.
    #
    # Note 2: The example entries below illustrate that in some cases
    # the two character 'Language' abbreviation is not identical to
    # the two character 'Country' code for its country,
    # E.g. 'Danmark/dk' versus 'Danish/da'.
    #
    # Note 3: In the case of 'ltz' we violate the RFC by using a three char
    # specifier. There is 'work in progress' to fix this and get
    # the reference data for rfc1766 cleaned up.
    #
    # Catalan (ca) - Croatian (hr) - Czech (cs) - Danish (da) - Dutch (nl)
    # English (en) - Esperanto (eo) - Estonian (et) - French (fr) - German (de)
    # Greek-Modern (el) - Hebrew (he) - Italian (it) - Japanese (ja)
    # Korean (ko) - Luxembourgeois* (ltz) - Norwegian Nynorsk (nn)
    # Norwegian (no) - Polish (pl) - Portugese (pt)
    # Brazilian Portuguese (pt-BR) - Russian (ru) - Swedish (sv)
    # Simplified Chinese (zh-CN) - Spanish (es) - Traditional Chinese (zh-TW)
    #
    AddLanguage ca .ca
    AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
    AddLanguage da .dk
    AddLanguage de .de
    AddLanguage el .el
    AddLanguage en .en
    AddLanguage eo .eo
    AddLanguage es .es
    AddLanguage et .et
    AddLanguage fr .fr
    AddLanguage he .he
    AddLanguage hr .hr
    AddLanguage it .it
    AddLanguage ja .ja
    AddLanguage ko .ko
    AddLanguage ltz .ltz
    AddLanguage nl .nl
    AddLanguage nn .nn
    AddLanguage no .no
    AddLanguage pl .po
    AddLanguage pt .pt
    AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
    AddLanguage ru .ru
    AddLanguage sv .sv
    AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
    AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw

    #
    # LanguagePriority allows you to give precedence to some languages
    # in case of a tie during content negotiation.
    #
    # Just list the languages in decreasing order of preference. We have
    # more or less alphabetized them here. You probably want to change this.
    #
    LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW

    #
    # ForceLanguagePriority allows you to serve a result page rather than
    # MULTIPLE CHOICES (Prefer) [in case of a tie] or NOT ACCEPTABLE (Fallback)
    # [in case no accepted languages matched the available variants]
    #
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

    #
    # Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
    # interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the
    # default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
    # in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
    # directive:
    #
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file mime.types for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-tar .tgz

    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    # Despite the name similarity, the following Add* directives have nothing
    # to do with the FancyIndexing customization directives above.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz

    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    #   MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
    #
    AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
    AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    #
    # For files that include their own HTTP headers:
    #
    #AddHandler send-as-is asis

    #
    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    # (This is enabled by default to allow the Apache "It Worked" page
    #  to be distributed in multiple languages.)
    #
    AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

    #
    # Action lets you define media types that will execute a script whenever
    # a matching file is called. This eliminates the need for repeated URL
    # pathnames for oft-used CGI file processors.
    # Format: Action media/type /cgi-script/location
    # Format: Action handler-name /cgi-script/location
    #

    #
    # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
    # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
    #
    # Some examples:
    #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
    #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
    #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
    #

    #
    # Putting this all together, we can internationalize error responses.
    #
    # We use Alias to redirect any /error/HTTP_<error>.html.var response to
    # our collection of by-error message multi-language collections.  We use
    # includes to substitute the appropriate text.
    #
    # You can modify the messages' appearance without changing any of the
    # default HTTP_<error>.html.var files by adding the line:
    #
    #   Alias /error/include/ "/your/include/path/"
    #
    # which allows you to create your own set of files by starting with the
    # /var/www/error/include/ files and
    # copying them to /your/include/path/, even on a per-VirtualHost basis.
    #

    Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    <IfModule mod_include.c>
        <Directory "/var/www/error">
            AllowOverride None
            Options IncludesNoExec
            AddOutputFilter Includes html
            AddHandler type-map var
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            LanguagePriority en es de fr
            ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
        </Directory>

    #    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 405 /error/HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 408 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_TIME_OUT.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 410 /error/HTTP_GONE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 411 /error/HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 412 /error/HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 413 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 414 /error/HTTP_REQUEST_URI_TOO_LARGE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 415 /error/HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 500 /error/HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 501 /error/HTTP_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 502 /error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 503 /error/HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.html.var
    #    ErrorDocument 506 /error/HTTP_VARIANT_ALSO_VARIES.html.var

    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The following directives modify normal HTTP response behavior to
    # handle known problems with browser implementations.
    #
    BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

    #
    # The following directive disables redirects on non-GET requests for
    # a directory that does not include the trailing slash.  This fixes a
    # problem with Microsoft WebFolders which does not appropriately handle
    # redirects for folders with DAV methods.
    # Same deal with Apple's DAV filesystem and Gnome VFS support for DAV.
    #
    BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
    BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully

    #
    # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
    # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
    # Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
    #
    #<Location /server-status>
    #    SetHandler server-status
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Deny from all
    #    Allow from .example.com
    #</Location>

    #
    # Allow remote server configuration reports, with the URL of
    #  http://servername/server-info (requires that mod_info.c be loaded).
    # Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
    #
    #<Location /server-info>
    #    SetHandler server-info
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Deny from all
    #    Allow from .example.com
    #</Location>

    #
    # Proxy Server directives. Uncomment the following lines to
    # enable the proxy server:
    #
    #<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    #ProxyRequests On
    #
    #<Proxy *>
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Deny from all
    #    Allow from .example.com
    #</Proxy>

    #
    # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
    # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
    # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block
    #
    #ProxyVia On

    #
    # To enable a cache of proxied content, uncomment the following lines.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html for more details.
    #
    #<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
    #   CacheEnable disk /
    #   CacheRoot "/var/cache/mod_proxy"
    #</IfModule>
    #

    #</IfModule>
    # End of proxy directives.

    ### Section 3: Virtual Hosts
    #
    # VirtualHost: If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
    # machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
    # use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
    # IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
    #
    # Please see the documentation at
    # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
    # for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
    #
    # You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
    # configuration.

    #
    # Use name-based virtual hosting.
    #
    #NameVirtualHost *:80
    #
    # NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
    # (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
    # SSL protocol.
    #

    #
    # VirtualHost example:
    # Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
    # The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
    # server name.
    #
    #<VirtualHost *:80>
    #    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    #    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
    #    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    #    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    #    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
    #</VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mydata.com
      ServerAdmin web-admin@mydata.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydata
      # MonoServerPath can be changed to specify which version of ASP.NET is hosted
      # mod-mono-server1 = ASP.NET 1.1 / mod-mono-server2 = ASP.NET 2.0
      # For SUSE Linux Enterprise Mono Extension, uncomment the line below:
      # MonoServerPath mydata.com "/opt/novell/mono/bin/mod-mono-server2"
      # For Mono on openSUSE, uncomment the line below instead:
      MonoServerPath mydata.com "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"

      # To obtain line numbers in stack traces you need to do two things:
      # 1) Enable Debug code generation in your page by using the Debug="true"
      #    page directive, or by setting <compilation debug="true" /> in the
      #    application's Web.config
      # 2) Uncomment the MonoDebug true directive below to enable mod_mono debugging
      MonoDebug mydata.com true

      # The MONO_IOMAP environment variable can be configured to provide platform abstraction
      # for file access in Linux.  Valid values for MONO_IOMAP are:
      #    case
      #    drive
      #    all
      # Uncomment the line below to alter file access behavior for the configured application
      MonoSetEnv mydata.com MONO_IOMAP=all
      #
      # Additional environtment variables can be set for this server instance using
      # the MonoSetEnv directive.  MonoSetEnv takes a string of 'name=value' pairs
      # separated by semicolons.  For instance, to enable platform abstraction *and*
      # use Mono's old regular expression interpreter (which is slower, but has a
      # shorter setup time), uncomment the line below instead:
      # MonoSetEnv mydata.com MONO_IOMAP=all;MONO_OLD_RX=1

      MonoApplications mydata.com "/:/var/www/html/mydata"
      <Location "/">
        Allow from all
        Order allow,deny
        MonoSetServerAlias mydata.com
        SetHandler mono
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
      </Location>
      <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
      </IfModule>
    </VirtualHost>
```

My mod_mono.conf file is as follows:

```
# mod_mono.conf

# Achtung! This file may be overwritten
# Use 'include mod_mono.conf' from other configuration file
# to load mod_mono module.

<IfModule !mod_mono.c>
LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "Mono"
</IfModule>

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asmx
AddType application/x-asp-net .ashx
AddType application/x-asp-net .asax
AddType application/x-asp-net .ascx
AddType application/x-asp-net .soap
AddType application/x-asp-net .rem
AddType application/x-asp-net .axd
AddType application/x-asp-net .cs
AddType application/x-asp-net .vb
AddType application/x-asp-net .master
AddType application/x-asp-net .sitemap
AddType application/x-asp-net .resources
AddType application/x-asp-net .skin
AddType application/x-asp-net .browser
AddType application/x-asp-net .webinfo
AddType application/x-asp-net .resx
AddType application/x-asp-net .licx
AddType application/x-asp-net .csproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .vbproj
AddType application/x-asp-net .config
AddType application/x-asp-net .Config
AddType application/x-asp-net .dll
DirectoryIndex index.aspx
DirectoryIndex Default.aspx
DirectoryIndex default.aspx
```

Kindly help me in resolving this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please help me with this issue guys. I'm stuck on this for days...

Comment: Please run gacutil -l | grep Extensions and see if you get the desired assembly. Also I think you are using mod_itk which seems having some problems. Finally, check that you are running mod_mono_server4 instead of mod_mono_server2